# High thermal conductivity in soft, fleece-like textiles

Tags: thermal

Fleeces typically exhibit low thermal conductivity, and are often used in winter clothing for their insulating properties.
I am seeking a material for a radiant heat application that is soft to the touch like fleece, but transmits heat well.

Measuring thermal conductivity in Watts per meter-Kelvin.

[This study](https://inpressco.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Paper241675-1678.pdf) found 15 fleece samples to all have thermal conductivity below 0.004 W/mK. Textiles with higher thermal conductivity include [leather](http://lib.buet.ac.bd:8080/xmlui/bitstream/handle/123456789/2996/Full%20Thesis.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) (0.1 to 0.15 W/mK) and [linen](https://thermtest.com/how-thermal-conductivity-decides-what-you-put-in-your-closet) (0.188 W/mK).

I understand that the air trapped within fleece will impede heat flow. So a heat-transmitting fleece might have very dense 'hairs' to shrink air pockets. Alternatively, the hairs may be shorter.

Heated blankets often incorporate fleeces. Do these blankets use particular fabrics to reduce insulative loss? Or do they just put out enough heat to compensate for the loss through poor conductivity?